# Should I represent a Java utilitary class in UML?

Tags: java, uml, interpreter, utilities

My text editor has three classes wich are `Buffer`, `Command` and `CommandInterpreter`. Buffer and Command are oriented object classes but `CommandInterpreter` contains only static method and is used to create an instance of Command and to execute these command.

My question is should I represent `CommandInterpreter` on my classes' diagram or should I just represent `Command` and `Buffer` since `CommandInterpreter` contains only static method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe invent your own stereotype "Utilitary" and just add that to the class diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to show with your UML

1. Show the object oriented design of the problem (than the `CommandInterpreter` is not needed)
2. Documentation of the whole system (in this case i would add the `CommandInterpreter` because otherwise something is missing)

I would prefer to add the `CommandInterpreter` (maybe with a short note as description). Also the stereotype `<<utility>>` can be used for classes which have only static methods.